# How can I find only the executable files under a certain directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find

How can I find only the executable files under a certain directory in Linux?

Comment: Here is a kind of BASH script, it is not-bad is what I can say :)  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20209457/2067125

Comment: What about using the standard [`file` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29)?

Comment: For anyone wanting to do this on a **Mac** (tested on OS X 10.9.5):

    `ls -l | egrep '^[^d]..x..x..x.*$'`

The above will list all executables (for all/user and group) in the current directory.

*Note*: The `-executable` option does not work on a Mac hence the above workaround.

Comment: Also relevant: [Unix find: search for executable files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458120/unix-find-search-for-executable-files)

Comment: @techfoobar: The question is ambiguous: Does it mean files that contain executable code, or does it mean files that have executable permission?  But even if we assume that executable permission is what is wanted (as the majority of the responses seem to), the question doesn't say **world-executable**.  Your solution will find files (and also fifos, sockets, symlinks, etc.) that have world execute permission, but not 750 (`-rwxr-x---`), which is still executable to some users.

Answer (score 208):

Checking for executable files can be done with `-perm` (not recommended) or `-executable` (recommended, as it takes ACL into account). To use the `-executable` option:

```
find DIR -executable
```

If you want to find only executable files and not searchable directories, combine with `-type f`:

```
find DIR -executable -type f
```

Comment: This will return files with the execute turned on only. A more thorough analysis would check for a shebang line or whether the file is binary

Comment: a shebang doesn’t mean they’re executable. it tells us only which interpreter to use. and by linux definition “executable files” are files with the executable (x) bit set

Comment: What version of find supports that type for -type? man find lists b, c, d, p, f, l, s and D on my system.

Comment: Same here, my find doesn't have a `-type x` either.

Comment: For some reason I always think that "-type x" will work too.  I can only imagine it was available on some flavour of Unix I used once.

Comment: @dave: glad to hear i’m not the only one :)

Comment: If you have an old version of find (probably before 4.3.8)  which lacks -executable use find . -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x.

Comment: -executable isn't at all portable and should be avoided

Comment: `find: invalid predicate -executable'` on RHEL

Comment: How about not executable? Seems like a good thing to add here...

Comment: @DanBolser that's as simple as `find -not -executable` (optionally with `-type f`, depending on whether you want to only include files in the result)

Comment: Thanks @knittl, worth editing the answer?

Comment: @DanBolser the discussion probably takes longer than actually updating the answer, but I think the answer is complete as it stands now. The OP was specfically about finding files which are executable, not about excluding them. I expect people to read the [find man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to some extent and they will find the basic `-not` operator there.

Comment: I can't edit it. I've been using find for years, but -executeable and -not are both new to me (just saying ;-)

Comment: It seems that if the `<dir>` is not present, then the directory is `.` by default. Is that correct?

Comment: @pmor For GNU find, yes, it defaults to `.`. On macOS the starting-point is mandatory.

Answer (score 43):

Use the find's `-perm` option. This will find files in the current directory that are either executable by their owner, by group members or by others:

```
find . -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x
```

Edit:

I just found another option that is present at least in GNU find 4.4.0:

```
find . -executable
```

This should work even better because ACLs are also considered.

Comment: This only works on a newer version of find. The one that comes by default with CentOS gives the error `find: invalid mode `/u=x,g=x,o=x'`

Comment: Then you should try the "-perm +" version which is now deprecated in GNU find: find . -perm +111"

Comment: Seems like `-perm /111` may be the most portable version.

Comment: Works with mine busybox on arm

Answer (score 41):

I know the question specifically mentions Linux, but since it's the first result on Google, I just wanted to add the answer I was looking for.

This is tested on macOS 10.12.5:

```sh
find . -perm +111 -type f
```

Comment: Works in RHEL 5 too.

Comment: This is the only variant I could get working on OS X 10.14, thx

Comment: Needed this while using a busybox build of find.  -executable did not work. `-perm +111` is perfect.

Comment: from the man page `-perm +mode This is no longer supported (and has been deprecated since 2005).  Use -perm /mode instead.`

Answer (score 8):

I have another approach, in case what you really want is just to do something with executable files--and not necessarily to actually force find to filter itself:

```
for i in `find . -type f`; do [ -x $i ] && echo "$i is executable"; done
```

I prefer this because it doesn't rely on `-executable` which is platform specific; and it doesn't rely on `-perm` which is a bit arcane, a bit platform specific, and as written above requires the file to be executable for everyone (not just you).

`.` will start searching the current directory. This can be replaced with any directory path.

The `-type f` is important because in *nix directories have to be executable to be traversable, and the more of the query is in the `find` command, the more memory efficient your command will be.

Anyhow, just offering another approach, since *nix is the land of a billion approaches.

Comment: (0) Which do you prefer, arcane and correct or intuitive and flawed?  I prefer correct.  (1) [innaM’s answer](http://superuser.com/a/39100/150988), featuring `find -perm`, finds files that have *any* execute permission bit set.  (2) By contrast, this answer finds only files for which the current user has execute permission.  Granted, that might be what the OP wants, but it’s unclear.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) For clarity, you might want to change `\`…\`` to `$(…)` — see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/23408), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838/23408), and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119/23408).  (4) But don’t do `for i in $(find …); do …`; it fails on filenames that contain space(s).  Instead, do `find … -exec …`.  (5) And, when you do work with shell variables, always quote them (in double quotes) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Comment: @scott OK, I stand corrected :)  I read the `-perm` argument as requiring all three, not one of them.  Also, thank you for the input on protecting shell arguments, that's all stuff I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @MarkMcKenna you have a typo in there: `for i in `find . -type f`; do [ -x $i ] && echo "$i is executable"; done`; you are missing the <dir> part, which I use a dot(.)

Comment: @Scott `find -exec` seems to fail if what I want to do is `source` the found file, so I'm using `for... do...`

Answer (score 4):

A file marked executable need not be a executable or loadable file or object.

Here is what I use:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*" -not -name "*.o" -exec sh -c '
    case "$(head -n 1 "$1")" in
      ?ELF*) exit 0;;
      MZ*) exit 0;;
      #!*/ocamlrun*)exit0;;
    esac
exit 1
' sh {} \; -print
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: @DerMike, It is one of the ways to find executable in current directory, including .so files, even if a file is not marked executable it can discover.

Comment: Well, I mean, _how_ does it do that?

Comment: It reads from the header of the file to discover, every binary file or script file has header.

Comment: As far as I know, `-name "*"` has no effect on `find` — it normally finds all files that are not eliminated by tests.

Comment: @AjayKumarBasuthkar you are aware this is NOT an answer to the question? the question was how to find executable files (=those that can be executed, = those w/ +x). not how to find all ELF, EXE and whatever-ocamlrun-is files.

Comment: @nonchip I strongly disagree. @OP did not ask what files were set to executable/+x, but what files were actually executable. The definition of what that means is left to the reader, but I would not consider `portrait.png` executable, even with `a+x`, and I would consider `/usr/bin/grep` an executable, even if it was accidentally changed to miss the `x` flag.

Comment: @Torque but `portrait.png` can be executable by your logic, just get a Piet interpreter. and even if then executable means "can be run with `./`" (which requires `x`) just configure `binfmt_misc`. also pretty sure the grammar "only the executable files" implies "only the files which are executable", not files that are of the few (of the many executable formats out there) you deemed worthy. that would be "only ELF files", "only programs" or similar. and you didn't find `.app`,`.py`, `.lua`, `.sh`, all executables (even usually with `./` from bash), unlike `.so` and `.dll`.

Comment: Those down voting the answer with or without verifying the functioning of the script, reflects their ability to reason, discover usefulness &/ learn, acknowledge our peers, knowledge & maturity.

Comment: The downvotes you’ve gotten so far reflect the belief that you’re answering the wrong question with a skimpy explanation. I wonder why you consider ``.so`` files to be executable but not ``.o`` files, and why you consider OCaml scripts to be executable but not shell scripts (or Awk, Perl, Python, etc.). Also, your answer has a typo. But *THIS* downvote is for the snarky, abusive comment.

Answer (score 3):

As a fan of the one liner...

```
find /usr/bin -executable -type f -print0 | xargs file | grep ASCII
```

Using 'xargs' to take the output from the find command (using print0 to ensure filenames with spaces are handled correctly). We now have a list of files that are executable and we provide them, one by one, as the parameter for the 'file' command. Then grep for the term ASCII to ignore binaries. Please substitute -executable in find command with what style you prefer (see earlier answers) or what works on your 'NIX OS

I required the above to find files with eval in scripts owned by root, so created the following to help find priv escalation weaknesses where root user runs scripts with unsafe parameters...

```
echo -n "+ Identifying script files owned by root that execute and have an eval in them..."
find /  -not \( -path /proc -prune \)  -type f -executable -user root -exec grep -l eval {} \; -exec file {} \; | grep ASCII| cut -d ':' -f1 > $outputDir"/root_owned_scripts_with_eval.out" 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: That won't work if the script contains non-ASCII characters. `file` reports the encoding, so a python script can be reported as `a /usr/bin/python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable`.  `find ... | xargs file -b | grep -v '^ELF'` could work better to spot the non-binaries.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function in `~/.bashrc` tonight to find executable files not in the system path and not directories:

```bash
# Quickly locate executables not in the path
xlocate () {
    locate -0r "$1" | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c '[[ -x "$1" ]] && [[ ! -d "$1" ]] \
        &&  echo "executable: $1"'  _  {}
} # xlocate ()
```

The advantage is it will search three Linux distros and a Windows installation in under a second where the `find` command takes 15 minutes.

For example:

```bash
$ time xlocate llocate
executable: /bin/ntfsfallocate
executable: /home/rick/restore/mnt/e/bin/llocate
executable: /mnt/clone/bin/ntfsfallocate
executable: /mnt/clone/home/rick/restore/mnt/e/bin/llocate
executable: /mnt/clone/usr/bin/fallocate
executable: /mnt/e/bin/llocate
executable: /mnt/old/bin/ntfsfallocate
executable: /mnt/old/usr/bin/fallocate
executable: /usr/bin/fallocate

real    0m0.504s
user    0m0.487s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Or for a whole directory and all it's subs:

```bash
$ time xlocate /mnt/e/usr/local/bin/ | wc -l
65

real    0m0.741s
user    0m0.705s
sys     0m0.032s
```

Comment: This is the solution I will be using. Very time-efficient, and I like being able to put it in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @bballdave025: That’s a red herring; *all* the answers could be put into ``.bashrc`` if you wanted to.

Comment: Good point, @Scott , and one that shows that my comment is inaccurate. Thanks for pointing it out, so that others will know. Even so, because of the time-efficiency of this process, I choose to put this one in `~/.bashrc`, rather than the others.

Answer (score 1):

This finds the word executable in the output of "file". You could also grep for "ELF". This will find binary executable files if they have +x (executable bit) set or not. Here's my variation.

```
find . | while read a; do [[ $(file -b "$a" | grep executable) != "" ]] && echo $a; done
```

Answer (score -1):

`fd -tx`

`fd` is a simple user friendly alternative to find written in rust.

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd