# Where is the sudo command

Tags: linux, sudo

I am trying to find out what command should be used to figure out where the sudo command resides. The question is: What command will show where the sudo command resides?

Comment: See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/108618).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `which` command to know where any command file is located.
`which sudo` should do the trick.

Comment: `which` is used to find out what command will execute when you type only that command into the terminal. You can use `whereis` to find all instances of a command.

Comment: @MichaelFrank ... or `which -a`, which will leave out man pages, etc...

Comment: @Attie Oooh, good to know! Although, `which -a` does not seem to do anything on my Xubuntu machine, while `whereis -b` will only search for binaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what `bash` will execute when you enter `sudo` in a bash prompt, enter

```
type sudo
```

This covers commands in the path, aliases, functions and built-ins.

Comment: I agree `type` is the way to go here. Using `type -a` is also handy, as it will show other instances of the command beyond the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, here is one way even if the executable is not in your path.  [How to find an executable](https://superuser.com/questions/38981/how-can-i-find-only-the-executable-files-under-a-certain-directory-in-linux/38982)

```
find / -perm +111 sudo
```